# How can I get the name of the last person who committed on a remote?

Tags: bash, git

I know that the option `-force-with-lease` allows me to push force only if I was last committer but I would like to allow overriding it:

```
git push playground $current_branch:master --force-with-lease

if ! [[ "$?" == "0" ]]; then
    last_committer="$(git some command)"
    ask_continue "the last committer was $last_committer, would you like to push force?"
    git push playground $current_branch:master --force
fi
```

In that example, I would like to know what `git some command` would be.

Comment: Your plan is **dangerous**! if `--force-with-lease` fails you should *always* check the remote history and *merge*  the remote state of the branch into yours or *rebase* onto it. pushing with `--force` in that situation will **remove** the other contributors changes from the history.

Comment: I want to remove the other contributors change, it is a playground environment where anyone can, well, play! Nonetheless, thank you for pointing that out for any user coming here. **Don't do this if you are not aware of it**.

Comment: Whatever they play, they don't play _working with git_. (And I expect the game not being fun)

Comment: @hek2mgl would you mind explaining your comment? I really didn't get it. My guess you are saying the _reason_ of my question is a bad one? If so, I have pretty legitimate needs, they just do not need to appear in the question.

Comment: Force pushing to a public branch can only end up in chaos because there is no way to populate this change to all users. Unless users manually rewrite their history, every push from a different user from there on needs to be a force push, overwriting the changes from the previous push.

Comment: @hek2mgl I'd agree with you, but heroku's way of deploying is via git push to the master. And this playground environement is a replication of the production on which anyone can try his branch before making a pull request. So in that particular case, it is absolutely fine. And the _push guard_ I'm looking for (and found one, in fact, but it is heroku oriented), is a great plus for our team: to know from whom you can take the playground.

Comment: I would create a development branch and work with pull requests to synchronize the work on that development branch. Once a release should be created, merge the development branch into master, tag it and push it to heroku.

Comment: This is what we do for the staging environment. This _playground_ is just for any dev to experiment. Anyways, that is really not what the question is about, and I think the first comment warning explains very well already. If you really want to show that it is dangerous I'm inviting you to edit the question. IMHO it has been clearly said already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`git show --quiet --pretty=format:%an`

`--quiet` - suppresses the diff output

`%an` - is the author name (For all other formats [click this](https://git-scm.com/docs/pretty-formats))

> If you want to look who made last commit on a specific branch

`git show --quiet --pretty=format:%an origin/branch-name`

Comment: So in my case `git show --quiet --pretty=format:%an playground/master`. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

In order get the last commit details for author-name, date and time is

`git log -1`

Here you can find more detail for getting commit history.
https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Basics-Viewing-the-Commit-History

hope this will help you.